# Content div to be minus of header and footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a div that equals full screen (x amount)  minus the header and the footer by using the height: calc(100% - 55px) in CSS how ever that leaves me with extra space as seen below

[image]

html :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.layout {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 64px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  width: 160px;
  transform: ease;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="sidebar" >sidebar</div>
          <div class="layout">
            <div class="header">header </div>
            <div class="content">content</div>
            <div class="footer">footer</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Yet running this here in the snippet works fine, what can the issue be ?

Comment: Can you post your full html? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: @chase Chrome Version 102.0.5005.62

Answer (score 1):

It is not the issue with your code, you are seeing browser white line which you should see also in any other websites (Test in websites with dark backgrounds) since your browser has that. If you make your code full screen you will also see that it exist again. You can try other browsers & themes but not the issue of your code